# How can I make a request authorized with Oauth with Mojo::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, oauth, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am currently trying to make this work:

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $req = Mojo::Message::Request->new;
my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full');

app->log->info($c->session('token'));
$tx->req->headers->authorization('Bearer ' . $c->session('token'));
```

where `$c->session('token')` is the token I got via [Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2](http://search.cpan.org/~jhthorsen/Mojolicious-Plugin-OAuth2-1.53/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OAuth2.pm).

I only get back an empty response. Doing the same (I think) via curl works OK:

```
curl -v -H "authorization: Bearer the_same_token_as_above" https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I see that you're missing is a [call to `start`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent#build_tx).  Adding the following two lines to your code block works for me (albeit with a different url/token):

```
$tx = $ua->start($tx);
app->log->info($tx->res->body);
```

If you have a lot of API calls that need to be authorized, then you might want to try the approach [similar to this](https://msoulier.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/custom-request-headers-in-mojo/), shown below:

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

$ua->on(start => sub {
    my ($ua, $tx) = @_;
    $tx->req->headers->authorization('Bearer <your token here>');
});

my $tx = $ua->get('<your first url here>');
app->log->info("Response body:", $tx->res->body);

my $tx = $ua->get('<your second url here>');
app->log->info("Response body:", $tx->res->body);

# etc...
```

The advantage of this technique is that each time you use the `get` method of that `UserAgent` instance, it will fire the start event listener and add the authorization header for you.